# Evento '.on('click', function(){});' dispara Multiplas Vezes

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Bom Dia,
Eu estou trabalhando em uma pagina onde tem varias `ul` dinamicas, ou seja com `li` sendo implementadas nelas via input e contadas atraves de diversas variaveis (uma para cada `ul`), e para facilitar fiz uma função de Excluir `li` global para todos as minhas `ul`,  a função ficou Assim:

```
$('.excluir_li').on('click', function(){
    var elemento = $(this);
    do{
        if(elemento.is('li')){ //Busca o Li a partir do botão de Excluir
            li = true;
        }else{
            elemento = elemento.parent();
        }
    }while(!li);

    switch(elemento.attr('class')){ //Indentifica de qual UL ela faz parte e atualiza o seu contador
        case 'sitProblemaSalvo': contSitProblema--; break;
        case 'SitAprendizagemSalvo': contSitAprendizagem--; break;
        case 'compTecnicoSalvo': contCompetenciasTecnicas; break;
        case 'compGestaoSalvo': contCompetenciasGestao--; break;
        case 'critCompTecnicoSalvo': contCriteriosCompTecnico--; break;
        case 'critCompGestaoSalvo': contCriteriosCompGestao--; break;
        case 'planoAulaSalvo': contPlanoAula--; break;
        case 'estrategiaPlanoAulaSalvo': contEstrategia--; break;
        case 'recursoPlanoAulaSalvo': contRecurso--; break;
        case 'intervencaoPlanoAulaSalvo': contIntervencao--; break;
    }

    elemento.remove();// remove a LI
    }
});
```

Porem ao executar eu notei que a função se executa o diversas vezes(o numero de `li` da lista para ser mais exato), eu pesquisei e tentei usar a função `e.preventDefault();` porem esta não foi efetiva, sera que alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você está executando esse trecho de código mais de uma vez? Caso sim esteja, vai acabar atribuindo o evento mais de uma vez a cada li existente no momento da execução.

Comment: eu estou executando este evento dentro de uma função e estou chamando ela toda vez que vou adicionar uma LI, eu fiz desta forma por que se não o evento não vinculava...

Comment: O ideal nesses casos é criar um único event listener num elemento mais acima na hierarquia, e que não seja dinâmico. Isso se chama delegação de eventos. Mas não dá pra dizer mais que isso sem conhecer seu html.